# STL sequential containers support insert (before) whereas forward_list support insert_after

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

STL sequential containers like vector, deque, list support insert to insert elements before given iterator to support statements like

vector.insert(std::end(container), container2.begin(), container2.end())

Whereas forward_list supports insert_after. Why STL maintainers had to make this design choice?

Comment: Because inserting before a given iterator is not implementable in constant time with the space efficiency provided by a forward list.

Answer (score 5):

`forward_list` is implemented as a singly-linked list. Each node in the list has a pointer to the next element in the list. (Note: pointer is a generic term here).

That means that moving backwards in the list is not possible. You *could* start at the beginning of the list, and move forward until you find the element whose link points to the item you have, but that's expensive. Inserting into a list in this manner is an `O(N)` operation (as opposed to `O(1)`)

All the other containers (`vector`, `string`, `deque`, `map`, `set`, `list`, etc) all support traversing forwards and backwards in the container, so it is simple to find the item "before".  `forward_list` does not.

As for the names, it would be more confusing if `insert(list_iter, x)` inserted before `list_iter`, but `insert(forward_list_iterator, x)` inserted *after* the position.  So the designers gave them different names.

[Later] This was discussed in the original proposal for `forward_list`, which can be found at: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2448.html. Thanks to Howard Hinnant for the link.